# Arduino: Change the color & color intensity of a LED periodically

Tags: c++, arduino

**Prerequisites:**

A RGB-LED is attached and wired to the [Arduino Uno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino_Uno)-board.

**Process description:**

In the beginning the LED is turned off.

A loop starts and an output-signal is put on the red-part of the LED.

With every iteration the output-signal becomes increased in the following way: 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

The loop stops after 255 (maximal red) is reached. After a delay the output-signal becomes decreased (by using a loop again) in the way: 255, 254, 253 ... until 0 is reached.

Then the increasing and decreasing starts again but this time with the green-part of the LED.

After the blue-part of the LED has been increased and decreased the whole process starts again with the red-part.

GitHub-README with [Image of the board-setup](https://github.com/mizech/arduino-projects)

**Implementation:**

```
   // -------- Declarations --------------
const int GREEN_LED_PIN = 9;
const int RED_LED_PIN = 11;
const int BLUE_LED_PIN = 10;
const int DELAY_WITHIN_LOOP = 10;
// ---------------------------------------

// ------- Own Functions -----------------
void setLed(int valRed, int valGreen, int valBlue) {
  analogWrite(RED_LED_PIN, valRed);
  analogWrite(GREEN_LED_PIN, valGreen);
  analogWrite(BLUE_LED_PIN, valBlue);  
}

void changeColorIntensity(int position, int step, int i, int stop) {
  while (i != stop) {
    switch (position) {
      case 0:
        setLed(i, 0, 0);
        break;
      case 1:
        setLed(0, i, 0);
        break;
      case 2:
        setLed(0, 0, i);
        break;
    }

    i += step;
    delay(DELAY_WITHIN_LOOP);
  } 
}
// -------------------------------------------

void setup() {
  pinMode(GREEN_LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RED_LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BLUE_LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    changeColorIntensity(i, 1, 0, 256);
    changeColorIntensity(i, -1, 255, -1);
  } 
}
```

The sketch works just fine and solves exactly the described task.

What annoys me is the part with the switch-statement and the multiple function-invocations.

If someone has an idea how to solve that part then his/her answer would be very appreciated.

Generally: **What would you have done different and why?**

Looking forward to reading your comments, recommendations and hints!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the switch statement smells. One way to avoid it is to abstract LED values into the array, and let `change_color_intensity` operate on it:

```
void change_color_intensity(int which, int start, int stop, int delta)
{
    int values[] = { 0, 0, 0 };
    for (values[which] = start; values[which] != stop; values[which] += delta) {
        set_leds(values[0], values[1], values[2]);
        delay(DELAY_WITHIN_LOOP);
    }
}
```

Note that I change a `while` loop into a IMHO more readable `for`. I also changed some names for the same reason.

---

Another approach is to abstract LED names, and get rid of `setLed` altogether:

```
void change_color_intensity(int which, int start, int stop, int delta)
{
    for (in value = start; value != stop; value += delta) {
        analogWrite(which, value);
        delay(DELAY_WITHIN_LOOP);
    }
}
```

with the caller defining a pin array:

```
    int LED = { RED_LED_PIN, GREEN_RED_PIN, BLUE_RED_PIN };
    for (pin = 0; pin < 3; pin++) {
        change_color_intensity(LED[pin], 0, 256, 1);
        ....
    }
```

---

I am not sure I understand what you mean by multiple function invocations. If you are concerned with invoking `change_color_intensity` twice in a loop, I see no problem with it.

Comment: I meant the three times setLed() with different parameter within the switch. Anyway: Thanks a lot for your answer. It‘s just great.